# Cannot read property 'action' of undefined in TFS at test summary

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, summary

One of my users is facing pretty strange error when trying to pull out test summary. I spent few hours researching yesterday but could not found anything related to TFS. Can You please have a look and help ?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF6Ul.jpg)

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? How do you pull out test summary? Do other users have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In order to indicate the issue is from client side or server side, you could try the items below:

1. Let the user pull out test summary from another machine.
2. Let the user login with other team member's account on this machine to see whether he/ she can reproduce this issue.
3. Try to clean the cache folder on the user's machine. The folder path is: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache`.

Comment: Hello, I asked user to do those things.1. Happens on all machines for all users 2. Clearning cache did not help. Any other ideas?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? How do you pull out test summary?